# Which scan to use to read floats from a string?

Tags: go

This seems almost right but it chokes on the newline.
What's the best way to do this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var z float64
    var a []float64
    // \n gives an error for Fscanf
    s := "3.25 -12.6 33.7 \n 3.47"
    in := strings.NewReader(s)
    for {
        n, err := fmt.Fscanf(in, "%f", &z)
        fmt.Println("n", n)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        a = append(a, z)
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Output:

```
n 1
n 1
n 1
n 0
[3.25 -12.6 33.7]
```

Update:

See the answer from @Atom below.  I found another way which is to break if the error is EOF, and otherwise just ignore it.  It's just a hack, I know, but I control the source.

```
    _, err := fmt.Fscanf(in, "%f", &z)
    if err == os.EOF { break }
    if err != nil { continue }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are parsing floats only, you can use `fmt.Fscan(r io.Reader, a ...interface{})` instead of `fmt.Fscanf(r io.Reader, format string, a ...interface{})`:

```
var z float64
...
n, err := fmt.Fscan(in, &z)
```

The difference between `fmt.Fscan` and `fmt.Fscanf` is that in the case of `fmt.Fscan` newlines count as space. The latter function (with a format string) does not treat newlines as spaces and requires newlines in the input to match newlines in the format string.

The functions with a format string give more control over the form of input, such as when you need to scan `%5f` or `%10s`. In this case, if the input contains newlines and it implements the interface [`io.RuneScanner`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#RuneScanner) you can use the method `ReadRune` to peek the next character and optionally unread it with `UnreadRune` if it isn't a space or a newline.

Comment: It's embarrassing.  I saw this function in the docs, but didn't know what to make of the a ...interface{}.  Then I found an example to copy that had Fscanf with &z as argument and I didn't think to go back to Fscan.  However, I still don't know what that function signature means.  Haven't found anything that would explain it yet.

Comment: The documentation for package `fmt` is explaining the `a ...interface{}` with the following sentence: "All arguments to be scanned must be either pointers to basic types or implementations of the Scanner interface".

Answer (score 2):

If your input is just a bunch of lines with floats separated by white space on each line, it might be easier to just read one line at a time from the file, run Sscanf on that line (assuming the number of floats on each line is fixed). But here's something that works in your example---there may be a way to make it more efficient.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var z float64
    var a []float64
    // \n gives an error for Fscanf
    s := "3.25 -12.6 33.7 \n 3.47"
    for _, line := range strings.Split(s, "\n") {
        in := strings.NewReader(line)
        for {
            n, err := fmt.Fscanf(in, "%f", &z)
            fmt.Println("n", n)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("ERROR: %v\n", err)
                break
            }
            a = append(a, z)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I know I can split first.  Was hoping for deeper understanding.  Meanwhile, I can make it work by doing "if err == os.EOF { break }" then "if err != nil { continue }" but it seems like a hack.  Not sure which error corresponds to "unexpected newline."